# H1b Visa stamping

Tags: h1-visa

I am on H1B visa. I have an approved H1B visa with validity date from 06/30/2018 to 07/24/2019 with my current employer. I am planning to travel to India in Feb 2019, during which I have to get my H1B visa with my current eployer stamped. Meanwhile I have got a new job offer and they are ready to start the H1b visa transfer process. They are ready to file a new petition for me and get the petition filed with USCIS. Also they are expecting me to join with the filed petition(without approval), for which I am ok. Even if the new company starts the visa transfer process and file a new petition now , I will be joining the new company only in March 2019, since I have to travel to India in Feb 2019 during which I have the visa stamping. So I want to know whether the visa transfer and petition from the new company cause any harm to my travel to India, visa stamping process for my current employer petition and port of entry while returning back to USA.